# Access to another child of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've HTML like that:

```
<div>
  <table>
  </table>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In JavaScript I have already access to this table. Now I want to get the other child element (div) from parent.

```
var par = table.parentNode;
var ch = $(par).children("div").first();
```

Actual I have an object, but when I try to add HTML like

```
ch.innerHTML = "Test";
```

I've no success. The text test is not added. If I would add the text to `par` itself, it works, but as soon as I get children with jquery, it does not work.

For debugging I alert the `par` and the `ch`. In case of `par` I see that I have HTMLDivElement, in case of `ch` it is only an Object.

What I am doing wrong?

Hint: Giving an id to the div and get it this way is not a solution for my application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ch` is referring to a jQuery collection of elements (alerts `[object Object]`) so what should work is

`ch[0].innerHTML = "Test";` (`ch[0]` = `[object HTMLDivElement]`)

or

```
 ch.html( "Test" );
```

I do not recommend the former in any case but just pointing out what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are using jQuery and Javascript in a very strange way, why are you using Javascript methods on jQuery objects?

If `$(par).children("div").first();` contains the correct object, you can set its html through jQuery like this:

```
$(par).children("div").first().html('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the `table` and wanting the `div`, you can use [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(table).siblings('div').first().html('Test');
```